# How to show product status in custom column?

Tags: magento2, custom-column-grid

I am creating a custom column in order grid and i am show the status **YES/NO** according to order status.

If product status complete then i will show **YES** in custom column otherwise processing, Canceled, hold, unhold and open then i am show **NO**.

[image]

Add additional column name is product status.

Answer (score 0):

It is quite simple and the reason is that you don't need any new data to make the job.
you may create a custom module in `app/code/Vendor/OrderGrid` .. (see screenshot of my module [image]

mine was `Mbs/OrderGrid`)
In the file `sales_order_grid.xml` you can define your column

select
                select
                Required

the class `Mbs\OrderGrid\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\OrderStatusRenderer` is what you need to get right:

```
    class OrderStatusRenderer extends \Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Column
    {
        /**
         * Prepare Data Source
         *
         * @param array $dataSource
         * @return array
         */
        public function prepareDataSource(array $dataSource)
        {
            if (isset($dataSource['data']['items'])) {
                foreach ($dataSource['data']['items'] as & $item) {
                    if ($this->getData('name') === 'status') {
                        if ($item[$this->getData('name')] == 'complete') {
  $result = 'Yes';
} else {
  $result = 'No';
}
    
                        $item[$this->getData('name')] = $result;
                    }
                }
            }
    
            return $dataSource;
        }
    }
```

hopefully, these infos answer your question